# How to fit image view into dialog activity with corners radius?

Tags: android

[image]

Background of ImageView contains animation-list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ep_stage1" android:duration="15" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ep_stage21" android:duration="15" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code of rounded corner Text view as like you can apply in image view:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#CCC" />
  <solid android:color="#E9967A" />
  <padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />
  </shape>
```

Apply in your background

Comment: background of image view contains animation list, how can I combine animation list and shape in single background file?

Comment: In background you can add

Comment: Background file can has only one root element ... or shape or animation ...